# Ordenar Python Data Frame (Pandas) em dois níveis

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho esse DataFrame e quero organiza-lo primeiro por nome e depois por ano, ou seja, sort ele em doís níveis.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
Country Name Country Code     Indicator Name Indicator Code   Ano    Pobreza
0        Aruba          ABW  Population, total    SP.POP.TOTL  1960    54211.0
1  Afghanistan          AFG  Population, total    SP.POP.TOTL  1960  8996351.0
2       Angola          AGO  Population, total    SP.POP.TOTL  1960  5643182.0
3      Albania          ALB  Population, total    SP.POP.TOTL  1960  1608800.0
4      Andorra          AND  Population, total    SP.POP.TOTL  1960    13411.0
```

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Está usando alguma biblioteca?

Comment: Usando Pandas. Eu sei que existe a função "pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()", mas eu quero organizar em dois níveis: Country Name e Ano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiquei na dúvida se entendi por completo, por isso criei uma nova versão dos dados e inclui 3 vezes a Albania com anos diferentes para checar o resultado.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
# Simulando um CSV
s = '''
"Country Name","Country Code","Ano","Pobreza"
"Aruba","ABW","1960",54211
"Afghanistan","AFG","1960",8996351
"Albania","ALB","2017",5643182
"Albania","ALB","1970",1608800
"Andorra","AND","1960",13411
"Albania","ALB","1900",2588
"Angola","AGO","1966",2588
'''
# read csv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=['Country Name', 'Country Code','Ano',
        'Pobreza'])
```

Agora vamos "printar" o dataframe:

```
print(df)
  Country Name Country Code   Ano  Pobreza
0        Aruba          ABW  1960    54211
1  Afghanistan          AFG  1960  8996351
2       Angola          AGO  1966  5643182
3      Albania          ALB  1970  1608800
4      Andorra          AND  1960    13411
5      Albania          ALB  1900     2588
6      Albania          ALB  2017     2588
```

Agora vamos fazer o sort no `df` atrbuindo o resultado a um novo dataframe (`df2`)

```
df2 = df.sort_values(['Country Name', 'Ano'])
```

Finalmente, vamos imprimir o resultado:

```
print(df2)
  Country Name Country Code   Ano  Pobreza
1  Afghanistan          AFG  1960  8996351
5      Albania          ALB  1900     2588
3      Albania          ALB  1970  1608800
2      Albania          ALB  2017  5643182
4      Andorra          AND  1960    13411
6       Angola          AGO  1966     2588
0        Aruba          ABW  1960    54211
```

É isso?

Comment: Isso. Eu queria ordelar primeiro por nomes e, como segundo argumento, os anos. Ajudaste. Obrigado!

Comment: Acrescentaria a resposta do anterior a possibilidade de inclusão do inplace = True.